# Why is Powershell deleting my private key after I import it?

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I have a Powershell script that imports a PFX certificate into the Machine store. This script is intended to be invoked by chef. When I run it manually, it works great. However, when chef runs it, it seems to only complete half its operation.

```
echo "Importing as PFX" >> $log

$rule = new-object security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule ".\IIS_IUSRS", "Read", allow

$pfx = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $file
$certThumbprint = $pfx.Thumbprint

echo "Thumbprint is $certThumbprint" >> $log

"$password" | certutil -ImportPFX "$certStoreLocation" "$file" >> $log

$keyPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\" + (((Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.thumbprint -eq $certThumbprint }).PrivateKey).CspKeyContainerInfo).UniqueKeyContainerName 

echo "Updating private key permissions: $keyPath" >> $log

$acl = get-acl -path $keyPath

$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)

# Allow IIS to read this private key
set-acl $keyPath $acl
```

In my log, I see successful output:

```
Examining certificate for import: c:\www\certificates\xyz.pfx
Importing as PFX
Thumbprint is 206E30F2694C8627C18EAE97729C643A3CC1317E
Enter PFX password: 
Certificate "xyz" added to store.

CertUtil: -importPFX command completed successfully.
Updating private key permissions: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\aee87c90ef6606b733130f970131e498_051677f6-7959-49c2-afb8-d2fad091409a
```

And, in MMC, I can see my certificate. However, the path listed in the log is missing, and when I try and examine the private key, it says it's missing. Again, when I run this as myself, it imports fine.

Thinking that I'm going insane, I used Process Monitor to see what's going on:

[image: Process Monitor output showing that the file is marked for deletion]

I don't know why, but it seems that Powershell marks the private key for deletion when it closes the file. What?? Why???

Notes:

- I cannot use Import-PFXCertificate, because it imports it as a CNG certificate, not a CSP certificate, which I lost 10-12 hours on.
- If I remove all the parts relating to setting the ACL, the issue doesn't happen. However, then my application can't read the private key.

Comment: I've been bashing my head on a similar/the same(?) issue. What I've found is that Chef runs as LocalSystem. What I suspect is that the cert was made with specific AD access which does not include local administer accounts. I don't know this for a fact yet but am interested to see what everyone comes up with.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for not using the existing Chef resources for managing certificates in Windows?

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows#windows_certificate

Your rceipe would then simply be a case of:

```
windows_certificate 'c:\www\certificates\xyz.pfx' do
   pfx_password    "my_password"
   private_key_acl [".\IIS_USRS"]
   store_name      "MY"
end
```